# UIView rotates while scaling using CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

Im using CGAffineTransformMakeScale to scale a UIView from 0.1 to 1.0.

The problem is that the view is also rotating while the scaling is being animated. So it ends with a scale of 1.0 AND 90º of rotation.

```
[self presentModalViewController:slideTwoViewController animated: NO];
[slideTwoViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1)];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[slideTwoViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The initial application orientation is landscape left. So when the animation ends the UIView looks like in portrait.

Is this supposed to happen? am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of UIView is it? Does this happen in the simulator and on the device?

Comment: ViewController's view, the default one. This happen in simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet, is the view already have a transform set and you are overwriting it with the new transform and it is animating the difference.

Try using the following function instead:

```
CGAffineTransformScale(<#CGAffineTransform t#>, <#CGFloat sx#>, <#CGFloat sy#>)
```

With this function, you pass the original transform `slideTwoViewController.view.transform` and your scale factor.

```
slideTwoViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(slideTwoViewController.view.transform, 0.1, 0.1);
```

Comment: Assuming that the initial slideVC.view.transform scale is (1.0, 1.0), using CGAffineTransformScale to (0.1,0.1) it does shrink correctly. But the initial scale must be 0.1, so when I scale it to the initial value CGAffineTransformScale(0.1,0.1) and then inside the block-animation I CGAffineTransformScale(1.0,1.0), there`s no animation and the scale is 0.1. The orientation of the UIView is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of scaling rootview try to add subview which become your new pseudo rootview (with all the rest subviews connected underneath) and then scale pseudo rootview. This way you are avoiding any transform collisions made by system on the real rootview (e.g. autorotating) and then you can use CGAffineTransformMakeScale freely.