# How do I prevent Pinch to Zoom Gestures from auto-rotating my AVCapture layer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Objective-C, iPhone iOS 6.0

The code below supports Portrait orientation fine, but when I try landscape, the pinch to zoom auto rotates it back to an awkward Portrait mode (but in Landscape view).

```
@implementation AVCapture
{
    CGFloat     beginGestureScale;
    CGFloat     effectiveScale;
}


- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)cameraView
{
    ......

    self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];

    [self rotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];

    [self.previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    self.previewLayer.frame = cameraView.frame;
    [self.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(cameraView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(cameraView.bounds))];
    [cameraView.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];

    effectiveScale = 1.0;

    ......
}


- (void)rotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    CALayer *previewLayer = self.previewLayer;

    switch (toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI+M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1); // 270 degress
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1); // 270 degress
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 1); // 270 degress
            break;

        default:
            previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0, 0, 1); // 270 degress
            break;
    }

}



// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#pragma mark Pinch to Zoom Gestures
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ( [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]] )
        beginGestureScale = effectiveScale;

    return YES;

}



- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer numberOfTouches] < 2)
        return;


    BOOL allTouchesAreOnThePreviewLayer = YES;
    NSUInteger numTouches = [recognizer numberOfTouches], i;

    for (i=0; i<numTouches; ++i)
    {
        CGPoint location = [recognizer locationOfTouch:i inView:m_CameraView];
        CGPoint convertedLocation = [self.previewLayer convertPoint:location fromLayer:self.previewLayer.superlayer];

        if (![self.previewLayer containsPoint:convertedLocation])
        {
            allTouchesAreOnThePreviewLayer = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allTouchesAreOnThePreviewLayer)
    {
        effectiveScale = beginGestureScale * recognizer.scale;

        if (effectiveScale < 1.0)
            effectiveScale = 1.0;

        CGFloat maxScaleAndCropFactor = [[self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] videoMaxScaleAndCropFactor];

        if (effectiveScale > maxScaleAndCropFactor)
            effectiveScale = maxScaleAndCropFactor;

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:.025];

        // Scale
        [self.previewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(effectiveScale, effectiveScale)];

        [CATransaction commit];
    }

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to maintain my transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726030/7599):
"... changing the orientation of preview layer doesn't change how the picture is captured. For that `AVCaptureConnection's setVideoOrientation:` method needs to be used."

.. and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12677074/7599).

```
[captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
```

So I replaced this:

```
[self rotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
```

with this:

```
[self.previewLayer.connection setVideoOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
```

Now it all works fine in landscape mode + pinch to zoom.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been answered here: [UIView rotates while scaling using CGAffineTransformMakeScale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218382/uiview-rotates-while-scaling-using-cgaffinetransformmakescale)

It seems to me that since you are rotating `previewLayer` manually, you need to adjust the recognizer accordingly, since you are overriding the transform with scaling. That happens because transformations are absolute, or atleast that's what I think about them.

How about using `CGAffineTransformScale` (as it was recommended in the question I've linked), where you can pass the original transformation of `previewLayer`, and the scale you want?

EDIT
Here are the docs for this problem: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html
There you can see that `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` is for **creating** transformations, and `CGAffineTransformScale` is for **changing** them, and I believe that's what you need.

EDIT2

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
   self.previewLayer.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.previewLayer.transform, effectiveScale, effectiveScale);
                 }];
```

Comment: I tried:
 ```[self.previewLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(self.previewLayer.affineTransform, effectiveScale, effectiveScale)];```
But the scaling then zooms out of control.

Comment: Could you please describe what _out of control_ means? Is the transformation doing the same like before?

Comment: The moment I pinch to zoom, the image scales in rapidly into pixel level, and I can't seem to zoom out anymore.  It's unusable.

Comment: That should not happen. What are common values of `effectiveScale`? Also, why do you multiply `recognizer.scale` with `beginGestureScale`, which should be the same, if I read the code correctly?

Comment: The original code isn't mine, so here I am fixing it. effectiveScale ramps up dramatically.  It's almost as if there needs to be some limit on the zoom.  Could it be because I'm using ```previewLayer``` on itself?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. What's weird to me after looking at the code again, however, is that in `rotateToInterfaceOrientation` you are setting normal transform, and in the `handlePinchGesture` method you are setting affineTransform. Also, I'm more used to this way of animating uiviews. (Edit2)
You could try to change it? Why do you use CATransaction anyway?