# How to rotate the UIStepper vertically after setting up its scale?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have set the scale of my stepper as follows :

```
m_stepper1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
```

After that if I try to rotate vertically, it doesn't make any effect on the stepper. It doesn't get rotated. I used the following code for rotation:

```
m_stepper1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
```

Please some one help me out with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218382/uiview-rotates-while-scaling-using-cgaffinetransformmakescale

Comment: That is for the view right? i want for the UIStepper, how to rotate it   vertically. It rotates if i don't set the scale but i want rotate it after setting the scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an extra view to accomplish this, all you need is a concat transform. The way you're doing this resets the previous transform before adding the new one. This will add both.

```
[stepper setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6))];
```

If however, you'd like to make the transforms one at a time, you should use one of the transforms that takes an input transform as a parameter. This will also produce the result you're looking for.

```
[stepper setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
[stepper setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(stepper.transform, 0.6, 0.6)];
```

Comment: Hey but there is one issue. I canon increase the width now i increased width to 500 in the stepper frame and checked,still there is no increase. Can you tell me how.

Comment: @user3202087 I don't know why that's happening, but if this solved the original problem then please mark it as correct by clicking the grey "check" next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You put the UIStepper on a UIView, and rotate UIView.

【edit】
The answer is my fault. Im sorry.
And correct answer is below.

The methods `CGAffineTransformMake~` and `CGAffineTransform~` have differences.
`CGAffineTransformMake~` use for transform FIRST TIME.
If you want to overlap transform, you should use `CGAffineTransform~`.

This is an example.

```
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6f, 0.6f);
stepper.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(scale, M_PI / 2.0f);
```

Please try this.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that as i am new to this.

Comment: Still it gives me the same original size of the stepper. i want to set the scale as (0.6,0.6) and the same size stepper i want rotate but with your code the size does decrease, it remains original.